# getting weird mongodb object on client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

well as i mentioned in the title when i'm sending message through socket to the server then save it in database mongodb with mongoose, then i returned the the message and send it back in the socket,
now when i tried to print it on console in the server right before i send it to the client with socket,
i got the object i wanted to send, but when i checked the object i got in the client, then i got diffrent object seems related to mongo probably(pretty sure) and i'm not sure what should i do to fix it.[this is what i get in the server right before i send it back to the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVjiZ.png)
[this what i get in the client when i recieve new message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Fd6.png)

```
const addMessage = async (newMessage) => {
  try {
    if (newMessage.type === 2) {
      const audioBlob = new Buffer.from(newMessage.message).toString("base64");
      newMessage.message = new Binary(audioBlob, Binary.SUBTYPE_BYTE_ARRAY);
    }
    const newMsg = new Message(newMessage);
    await newMsg.save();

   newMsg.message = Buffer.from(newMsg.message.buffer, "base64")

    return newMsg;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    errorHandler(error);
  }
};
```

i expected to get the same object i see in the server so in the client too

Comment: I think you sending whole object, but logging only ```_docs``` on the server side. try to emit only ```result._docs``` for example

Comment: Yeah. See also https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I found the problem, though i'm not sure how to describe it but the problem was here:

```
const newMsg = new Message(newMessage);
    await newMsg.save();

    newMsg.type === 2
      ? Buffer.from(newMsg.message.buffer, "base64")
      : newMsg.message;

    return newMsg;
```

so i took the newMessage and inserted newMsg.toJSON() to it;

```
if (newMessage.type === 2) {
      const audioBlob = new Buffer.from(newMessage.message).toString("base64");
      newMessage.message = new Binary(audioBlob, Binary.SUBTYPE_BYTE_ARRAY);
    }
    const newMsg = new Message(newMessage);
    await newMsg.save();
    newMessage = newMsg.toJSON();

    if (newMessage.type === 2) {
      newMessage.message = Buffer.from(newMessage.message.buffer, "base64");
    }

    return newMessage;
```

and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

you should always, provide code snippets while asking a question.

Th probable reason for the above problem is, you are printing the `console.log(result._docs)` and sending to the databse the complete `result` object. Try sending `result._docs` to your database as well.

P.S: `result` is just a variable to which your assigning the data. This variable may be different in your code.

(If this does not work, edit your question and attach code)

Comment: sry, I totally agree that I should have put a code sample...